Flutter web: Unable to run project

Currently, I am developing a mobile application and I want to run it on the web, but when I run the project, I encounter the error shown below:   Error when run project
Console in web: Error show in console web
Here is my flutter doctor output:
Flutter doctor

File main.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import 'app.dart';
import 'core/config/app_config.dart';
import 'injectable.dart';
import 'shared/src/app_constants.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await setPreferredOrientations();
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  configureDevDependencies();
  final Directory appDocumentDirectory =
      await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(appDocumentDirectory.path);
  await Hive.openBox(Constants.storageName);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

File index.html:
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="anmido_app">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>anmido_app</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    const serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>

File pubspec.yaml
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=3.2.3 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  # Commons
  cupertino_icons: 1.0.6
  intl: 0.18.1
  collection: 1.18.0
  tiengviet: 1.0.0
  fluttertoast: 8.2.4
  google_fonts: 6.1.0
  device_info_plus: 9.1.1
  keyboard_dismisser: 3.0.0
  flutter_svg: 2.0.9
  equatable: 2.0.5

  # State management
  provider: 6.1.1
  get: 4.6.6

  # Network
  dio: 5.4.0
  connectivity_plus: 5.0.2

  # Storage
  shared_preferences: 2.2.2
  flutter_secure_storage: 9.0.0

  # Responsive
  flutter_screenutil: 5.9.0
  responsive_builder: 0.7.0

  # Generated
  retrofit: 4.0.3
  json_annotation: 4.8.1
  freezed_annotation: 2.4.1

  # DI
  get_it: 7.6.6
  injectable: 2.3.2

  # Others
  flutter_spinkit: 5.2.0
  dropdown_search: 5.0.6
  shimmer: 3.0.0
  url_launcher: 6.2.3
  modal_bottom_sheet: 3.0.0-pre
  flutter_swipe_action_cell: 3.1.3
  cached_network_image: 3.3.1
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: 24.1.45+2
  flutter_animate: 4.4.0
  lottie: 2.3.2
  animated_splash_screen: 1.3.0
  number_selector: 1.0.7
  syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: 24.1.45
  curved_navigation_bar: 1.0.3
  flutter_widget_from_html: 0.14.11
  easy_date_timeline: 1.0.3
  syncfusion_flutter_gauges: 24.2.9
  numberpicker: 2.1.2
  weekly_date_picker: 1.4.2
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: 0.7.0
  quill_markdown: 0.1.0
  flutter_quill: 8.6.4
  markdown: 7.1.1
  uuid: 4.4.0
  html2md: 1.3.1
  qr_code_scanner: 1.0.1
  permission_handler: 11.1.0
  hive: 2.2.3
  path_provider: 2.1.3
  syncfusion_flutter_calendar: 24.1.45

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: 3.0.1
  freezed: 2.4.6
  build_runner: 2.4.7
  json_serializable: 6.7.1
  retrofit_generator: 8.0.6
  flutter_gen_runner: 5.4.0
  injectable_generator: 2.4.1

flutter_gen:
  output: lib/shared/gen/
  integrations:
    flutter_svg: true
  colors:
    inputs:
      - assets/color/colors.xml
    outputs:
      class_name: AppColors
  assets:
    outputs:
      class_name: AppAssets

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/png/
    - assets/svg/
    - assets/animation/


I have tried:

flutter channel stable
flutter config --enable-web
flutter run -d chrome


I would like to know what error my project is currently facing and how I can run my project on the web. I would greatly appreciate any support. Thank you.


Please include relevant information, formatted appropriately, in the question itself
